# Endpoint que cuando consulte a través del pot actualice un campo en la base de datos

Tags: python, django

¿Cómo puedo hacer un endpoint que cuando consulte a través del pot actualice un campo en la base de datos? Estoy usando Rest Framework.

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets 
from .models import Project
from .serializers import ProjectSerializers
class ModeloView(APIView):
     def get(self, request):
        queryset = Project.objects.all()
        serializer = ProjectSerializers(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
     
     def post(self, request):
        serializer = MiModeloSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
     

     def put(self, request, pk):
        instance = MiModelo.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = MiModeloSerializer(instance, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

     def delete(self, request, pk):
        instance = MiModelo.objects.get(pk=pk)
        instance.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: ¿Qué es un "pot"? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.